# Hypothesis Test of 2 binomial distributions with unknown and unequal variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, variance, binomial-distribution

I want to double check if my math and logic is correct in performing a hypothesis test of two sample means from binomial distributions with the assumption of unknown and unequal variances from the sample.

When $\sigma_1^2 \neq \sigma_2^2$ and our sample sizes are large enough our test statistic becomes
$$\frac{\bar{y_1}-\bar{y_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_2^2}{n_2}}} \sim N(0,1)$$

When our sample means are from the binomial distribution our sample means are
$$\bar{y} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i}}{n}$$

Thus the variance of our sample mean is
$$Var(\bar{y}) = Var(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i}}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2}Var(\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i})=\frac{n}{n^2}Var(y)=\frac{1}{n}Var(y) = \frac{1}{n}n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}) = \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$$

Would it not follow then that our test statistics of 2 sample means from the binomial distribution with unknown and unequal variances become
$$\frac{\bar{y_1}-\bar{y_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_2^2}{n_2}}}=\frac{\bar{y_1}-\bar{y_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p_1}(1-\hat{p_1})}{n_1}+\frac{\hat{p_2}(1-\hat{p_2})}{n_2}}}$$

Am I performing this test correctly? Working with the binomial distribution, the sample size in the equation tends to cause me to question my work

Comment: As always, the denominator in a $Z$ (or $t$) statistic is the SD of the numerator.  You have computed the variances of each term in the numerator and, since they are independent, you simply add those variances (and take the square root of the result).  Your extra divisions by the $n_i$ are therefore superfluous and incorrect.